# DataAdapter Missing Record

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ado.net

We execute mySQL Statement to data reader (7 records) with VB.net then load to a DataTable (Newly created 6 records?) via the code below - The first record seem to abscond when the datatable becomes involved - I cannot fathom why - ur wisdom is most appreciated.

```
SQL = "SELECT Count(total) as 'Inv #', CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%m'), '/', DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y')) AS Month, SUM(total) AS 'Total' FROM (tblinvoices) GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%m%Y') ORDER BY Month DESC"
                Try
                    myCommand.Connection = MysqlConn
                    myCommand.CommandText = SQL
                    myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
                    myData = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
                    myData.Read()     <- perfect 7 records
                Catch ex As MySqlException
                    MsgBox(ex.Number & ", " & ex.Message)
                Finally
                    Dim MyInvoiced As New DataTable
                    MyInvoiced.Load(myData) <- 6 records???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it without the line.

```
myData.Read()
```

It is positioning you at the second record.